# How can i set prefech size in clojure.contrib.sql?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I want select 1000000 rows from oracle database to coherence for analysis.
i use clojure.contrib.sql to select db. and in jdbc ,i can set setFetchSize(1000) ,
can i set fetchsize in clojure.contrib.sql ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to do this within clojure.contrib.sql because no hook is exposed to operate on the PreparedStatement before the query is executed.

I've opened a JIRA issue against clojure.java.jdbc - the new replacement for clojure.contrib.sql - to expose some way to allow this:

http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/JDBC-6

Your only option right now is to work directly with the low level parts of the library to get hold of a PreparedStatement and call (.setFetchSize stmt 1000) yourself, and then process the parameters and run the query. Ugly. I'll fix it :)